# Most efficient way to convert Task to Task<Unit>?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I have a high throughput queuing arrangement whereby I take in a `Func<Task>` and wish to project that to `Func<Task<System.Reactive.Unit>>` to fit nicely into an downstream Rx system.

Since `Unit.Default` is the only value for this, it feels like this should be very easy but I want it to be as efficient as possible.  I wish to pass through all exceptions from the original `Task` in the correct manner.

My current approach is:

```
public Task<Unit> QueueTaskRx(Func<Task> task)
{
    Func<Task<Unit>> f = async () =>
    {
        await task();
        return Unit.Default;
    };

    return QueueTask(f);
}
```

but I am worried about the overhead of the `async/await`

Perhaps another, more efficient way would be:

```
public Task<Unit> QueueTaskRx(Func<Task> task)
{
    Func<Task<Unit>> f = () => task().ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        // What other cases do I need to consider here??
        if (_.IsFaulted && _.Exception != null)
            throw _.Exception.InnerException;

        return Unit.Default;
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

    return QueueTask(f);
}
```

But this doesn't feel as safe and is more complex, branches etc

Does anyone have a better way?

Comment: *but I am worried about the overhead of the async/await* Why? Have you tested this code and found the state-machine struct generated by the compiler to be the most significant overhead?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thanks - Yes, I have tested it in a tight loop and found it was approx 46% slower using `async/await` vs `ExecuteSynchronously` `ContinueWith`

Comment: Perhaps you can share with us your measurement code and performance results.

Comment: Seems my benchmarks were poor & was jumping to conclusions - I found an issue and seeing far closer results now.

Comment: I would recommend using [*BenchmarkDotNet*](https://github.com/PerfDotNet/BenchmarkDotNet), it does all the heavy lifting for you, leaving you only to write the tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `async`/`await`, also adding a `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

You *could* do it with `ContinueWith`, but that would only save you some really tiny amount of time (like a single bitwise flag check and a single reference copy). It would cost a lot in complexity:

- `ContinueWith` should always specify a `TaskScheduler`.
- In addition to exceptions, you should handle cancellation, since that's treated specially by `Task`.

For other pitfalls, see my [Tour of `Task`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html) blog series (sadly still incomplete), where I attempt to enumerate all the problems using the "old" APIs can cause (e.g., `ContinueWith`).

Comment: Good call on the `ConfigureAwait(false)`

Answer (score 1):

I implemented what you need [here](https://github.com/ExRam/ExRam.Extensions/blob/master/ExRam.Extensions/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskExtensions%20%28AsUnitTask%29.cs). I used another extension for tasks called `Then` which was inspired by [Stephen Toub's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx).